# Markdown to HTML: script compatible with WSH

Tags: jscript, wsh, pagedown

There's a Markdown-to-HTML converter at [Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) project (JS script).
My question is: how can I adapt this JS script to WSH (Windows Script Host) usage? I need e.g. js script which can be called by WSH command line:

```
cscript.exe md_to_html.js c:\test\aa.md
```

I didn't find such page in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create WSF-file named **pagedown.wsf** with the following script

```html
<job>
    <object id="Stream" progid="Adodb.Stream" /> <!-- utf-8 documents support -->
    <script language="jscript" src="Markdown.Converter.js" />

    <script language="jscript">
            Stream.Charset = 'utf-8';
            Stream.Open();
            Stream.LoadFromFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

            var text = Stream.ReadText();

            WSH.Echo(new Markdown.Converter().makeHtml(text))
    </script>
</job>
```

and use it with **cscript.exe**

```
cscript //Nologo pagedown.wsf input.md > output.html
```

In case of troubles with ADODB try to download and install it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=5793).